# Gitlab multiproject pipeline points to the old commit when rerunning it

Tags: testing, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, multi-project

We've got a multi-project pipeline:

Project A:

```
...

stages:
- build
- test

build:
  stage: build
  some long building job setup

release testing:
  stage: test
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    - /^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
  when: on_success
  trigger:
    project: projectB
    branch: release
    strategy: depend
...
```

Project B:

```
...

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - run_tests.sh
```

Whenever a new release is rolled out on project A we trigger a multi-project pipeline on project B to test it automatically. Once we see the fails in B (due to the changes in A) we want to update the tests in B and commit them to release branch. Then we want to retrigger 'release testing' pipeline multi-project pipeline to verify the test changes are correct.

But we have a problem here. Once the multi-project pipeline is triggered it ties to a specific commit in project B. And if you click rerun on the Downstream job of A it will still run against the same commit in B. Is there a way to pick the latest commit of the target branch once you rerun the job other than retriggering the whole project A pipeline?